# Highchart Heatmap: Why only every second datavalue is displayed?

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

why in this highchart heatmap fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj7mosL1/) only every second data value is displayed? I like to display all values. Is there any option?

There is many data to be displayed. But i like to display all values of each element inside the heatmap. Maybe i need to resize it? With smaller heatmaps it works great. All data is displayed. But if i add more data the value wont display on each cell.

I hope you can help?

The code is complete in the jsfiddle. I have shorten the code here.

```
    function getPointCategoryName(point, dimension) {
    var series = point.series,
        isY = dimension === 'y',
        axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
    return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'TEST',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 1],[0, 1, 2],[0, 2, 3],[0, 3, 4],[0, 4, 5],[0, 5, 6],[0, 6, 7],[0, 7, 8],[0, 8, 9],[0, 9, 10],[0, 10, 11],[0, 11, 12],[0, 12, 13],[0, 13, 14],[0, 14, 15],[0, 15, 16],[0, 16, 17],[0, 17, 18],[0, 18, 19],[0, 19, 20],[0, 20, 21],[0, 21, 22],[0, 22, 23],[0, 23, 24],[0, 24, 25],[0, 25, 26],[0, 26, 27],[0, 27, 28],[0, 28, 29],[0, 29, 30],[0, 30, 31],[1, 0, 32],[1, 1, 33],[1, 2, 34],[1, 3, 35],[1, 4, 36],[1, 5, 37],[1, 6, 38],[1, 7, 39],[1, 8, 40],[1, 9, 41],[1, 10, 42],[1, 11, 43],[1, 12, 44],[1, 13, 45],...],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value.charAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels are too close to each other and some of them are hidden. To show all of them enable the `allowOverlap` property:

```
dataLabels: {
  ...,
  allowOverlap: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3nfpb8cu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.dataLabels.allowOverlap

Comment: Thanks man, it works! But how can i make the boxes larger?

Comment: Hi @Mike, You can manipulate `chart.height` and `chart.width` properties. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4536tqhe/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek thanks! But the height of the chart is not fix. I create it dynamicaly. Can i set a hight of a single cell or row?

Comment: No, but you can dynamically set chart size, for example depending on points amount: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p50oqcnk/